# What causes a black hole to be hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, black-holes, temperature, entropy

From my limited understanding of physics, it seems that the heat of a black hole is caused by vibrations in quanta of space, where quanta of space can be viewed as the elementary building blocks of a black hole.

Examining black hole heat is apparently important because it is a useful way of investigating the intersection of quantum mechanics, general relativity, and thermodynamics.

This is what I've understood from reading Carlo Rovelli's books: '7 Brief Lessons on Physics' and 'Reality Is Not What It Seems', but it is unclear to me whether his ideas about black hole heat are agreed upon by physicists, hence my question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hot'? A black hole is rather cold: https://phys.org/news/2016-09-cold-black-holes.html

Comment: All visible blackholes are cold and the supermassies have a temp. of about billionths of 1 kelvin. Only theoretically possible microblackholes have superhot temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

Black holes were discovered to possess entropy. Thermodynamically, having entropy implies that they must possess a temperature above absolute zero. To possess any temperature above absolute zero means they therefore must radiate heat. The math indicates that the temperature of a macroscopic black hole is very very close to absolute zero, but not equal to it, and that the smaller a black hole is, the greater its temperature.

Comment: I think the condition you want is not only "black holes have entropy," but rather, "black holes have entropy, _and this entropy increases when energy is added to the black hole_." This rules out negative temperatures, by $\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}$.

Comment: This was the shortest answer I could think up that didn't have any equations in it ;-)